# Alfresco models

Tags: repository, workflow, alfresco, models

Can somebody bring the light on the following issue - I can't figure out the difference between alfresco workflow model and repository model. Are they different ? Can I use them together, or one inside the other ?

Comment: One is used for storing data, one is used for holding workflow variables?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. One model is for workflow data which maps to workflow forms and the other one is for storing content in custom repository. It seems that the best way to use them both - is to create custom content in some listeners in a workflow ( like use models separately )

Comment: A workflow type is only used to define the variables that will be stored in the workflow and task instance. These workflow objects are not Alfresco nodes. You won't be able for example to execute a lucene search in Alfresco to search task instances.

Answer (score 2):

Workflow model deals with the Business Process Modeling(BPM), where you would manage flow of different tasks to user by user. On the other hand there is a 'Content Model' which is independent of workflow model, and it deals with your content types, properties and constraints within the content model. Both are different and independent, however you can use both of them together.